# CakePHP from localhost to remote server - blank page

Tags: cakephp

i am trying to figure this out for a long time now, but so far no luck, maybe somebody can help me.

I have a 2.2.2 cakephp installed on my computer (localhost) and everything works perfectly. But now i want that same project to be online on remote server. I upload everything, set mysql path but i get a blank page when trying to access the site.

If i upload a fresh cakephp it works, but my project doesnt. The debug is set to default, think that should be 2? I also deleted files in cache/tmp, but still no errors or anything, just blank page.

Any info would be helpful, thank you.

Comment: Did you check the logs of your webserver?

Comment: Change debug mode to 2 in order to see if it displays any error message. Also, don't forget to change the database configuration if you changed the DB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The real problem was only the coding I used in notepad++. All my files were encoded with UTF-8, but they should have been UTF-8 without BOM. After I changed it to UTF-8 withot BOM, everything started to work perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

I hate when that happens :). Usually it does if there is an error somewhere and you can't see it because the errors are turned off, so you should call phpinfo() and see if display_errors is on. Changing the debug mode doesn't work every time since display_errors is set from php.ini.

Unfortunately, if this is the problem and you don't have access to edit the php.ini file, you might need to ask the hosting provider to change it and restart the php service.

You can also try this: error_reporting(E_ALL)

Comment: Hey, i made some progress, the site actually works if i disable authorisation for example: $this->Auth->allow('index', 'view');. In this case indexes and views start to work, but i am still geting blank page on sites which require authorisation. You have any idea why this is happening? thanks.

Comment: Do the pages that are still blank require authorisation or maybe they use something from the users module? Also, have you checked if display_errors from phpinfo() is on? It's difficult to debug if you can't see any errors.

Comment: display_errors is on. Every page that requres authentication is using something from User() ofcourse. And one more thing, if i manually navigate to users/login and i submit login info i can see that it gets data from database (sql_dump) but it doesnt redirect me or set a session for logged user. Thanks

Comment: Ok, now the problem is ever more isolated, i figured out that blank pages show up whenever i use redirect of any kind, so it must be some kind of problem with redirect. Any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I uploaded changes to my cakephp website and discovered that all actions for a particular controller returned a blank page.  I discovered what the error was and was able to reproduce it with another controller.

The problem was that in the first line of my controller file I had a space before the opening php tag.

One space cost me hours.

Comment: I found the space was there in the AppController. I too wasted hours trying all options. Thanks:)

Answer (score 0):

Just uploading all files won't cut it. Make sure you work through this checklist:

1. First and foremost, check the error log file located under `app/tmp/logs/error.log`, this usually holds some very good pointers as to what is wrong.
2. Make sure you have uploaded the app/Config/database.php file with the *proper* details. Local installs usually have user `root` without password. Online servers (obviously) do not!
3. To that extent, also make sure you actually have a database with your hosting provider (either your host sent you the info or you need to create it yourself using their control panel).
4. Make sure you also uploaded all `.htaccess` files (the one under the root directory and `/app` and `/app/webroot`), some FTP programs don't show this "hidden" file by default.

If all else fails, contact your hosting provider for further support as they usually have access to more verbose server logs that can also hold clues.

Comment: Thanks for help, sadly i still havent figured it out.

There is absolutely nothing in error.log.
database.php is ok, i changed all parameter so it connects ok
.htaccess are all uploaded
So there is nothing else for me to check but ask the hosting provider? (doubt they will be able to help me, because a fresh install of cakephp works.)